# CodeIgniter Ajax does not populate content in modal form

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

The modal form called does not load the content using Ajax. So I have a modal dialog that is supposed to come up with a dropdown and Cancel & OK buttons. The dropdown is loaded from database, however it comes up empty.

I've tried to look this up but examples are either close or very far but none offered something similar.

I've also tried different approaches but still I end up with the same issue.

View:

```
foreach($aRecords as $record)
...
<a href="#" 
   class="btn btn-primary btn-xs change_parent_class"
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#confirmChangeParent" 
   id ="<?php echo $record->id; ?>"
><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> Change Parent</a>
```

The modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="confirmChangeParent" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmChangeParent" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Change Parent</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Please select one of the following options</p>
                <div id="areaChangeParent" name="areaChangeParent"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Cancel
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs default" id ="confirmSubmitDelete">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> Move
                </a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //function change_parent(id)
        $(".change_parent_class").click(function()
        {
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert("p-aci:" + id);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>project/project_issue/get_parents/",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {mid:id},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#areaChangeParent").html(data);

                    }
            });
        });
    });
```

Controller function to fetch data is in a dummy state just for testing:

```
function get_parents()
{


                    echo "bla";
                    return "bla bla";
}
```

No matter what the prompt is displayed but empty.

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I don't see any errors in browser (if that is what you ask)

Comment: i meant in the developer tools console (can google to find out where and what it is if you don't know). also you have `e.preventDefault();` without `function(e)`

Comment: thanks a million times my friend, you just gave me the tool I needed. I was in Mozilla FIrefox, but this solves a lot of future problems, too

Comment: and yes, that was the issue, the ```e.preventDefault();```

Comment: glad to help, funny that was actually the error. fyi, mozilla also has developer tools console (infact, most browsers do). anything you `console.log()` will come up in the console portion, and any 404 errors .etc. will show up red under the network pane. you can even check your reponses from ajax requests. once you learn how to properly use it, it will be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `e.preventDefault();` without `function(e)`